# Starling SetChildIndex performance issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, starling-framework

I have a Problem with the performance of `Sprite.setChildIndex`.
I have to display a world that consists of many small Images.  (about 10.000)

To have the best performance, i use a image pool and all images are allways in the display List of one Sprite, so I do not have to add and remove the images.

If I want to display a new Region of the world I only have to move the images to the new position. This process is really fast and takes about 6 ms.

But the problem is, that the order of the images in the display List is important to me. 
Because of that i have to use setChildIndex to rearrange the images. The process of setting the images to the correct position in the display List (setChildIndex) has a deep impact to the performance and so I need about 60 ms to display a new Region.
Do you have a idea how to optimize the process or is there a alternative to the setChildIndex method?

Answer (score 0):

You could give each Region of the world its own container, and put that container in a world container. This way, you can setChildIndex or swapChildren with a grouping of, say, 500 images rather than 10,000. And, if you want to load up a new Region, you can just setChildIndex on the entire Region container (within the world container). This will optimize map loading, rather than having to pay attention to all 10,000 sprites.